# How to monitor child process output and exit status without adversely affecting child?

Tags: unix, process, signals, stdout, exit

I want my program to monitor some processes that it has started.  These are the most important requirements I know of:

1. Record the exit status of the child processes (unless they exit after my program has exited).
2. Record the stderr and stdout output.  Ideally within a few seconds of its being written, but that is not a hard requirement: it would probably be enough to read it only when a user requests it.
3. Sometimes, the child processes will outlive my program.  Other times, they will not.  It's important that my program doesn't make the child processes more likely to exit in a way that might inconvenience my users -- for example, Unix signals sent to my program shouldn't kill the child processes as a side-effect.  If the parent exits, the children should continue running unaffected.
4. Ideally, the parent would track forks of the children so they can be monitored and perhaps signalled.  This is not a hard requirement, though.
5. The scheme needs to work on both Linux and OS X.

My resolution is to do all of the standard operations required to daemonize a process, except for the second fork.  Before doing that, I redirect output to a temporary log file, then monitor the log file using inotify (on Linux) or kqueues (on OS X).

As far as I know, the only loss to my stability requirement (3.) of omitting the second fork is if the child process obtains a controlling tty.

Is this solution a good one for these requirements?  What bad things could happen to the child processes that I haven't considered?

Comment: What processes do you plan to run?  Do those processes need terminal input?  Do the processes need to get signals?  You've got a ton of work ahead of you to monitor the standard output and standard error if the processes need to be interactive; you'll need a pseudo-tty (probably).  You'll need to run the processes in a separate process-group from your process so that your program might be able to exit without affecting the children too much - but the pseudo-tty monitoring is going to get in the way of that.  Parents cannot readily track grandchildren.  Linux has `/proc` but Mac OS X does not.

Comment: Non-interactive processes.  The signal behaviour of the programs is mostly unknown.

Comment: The process group does not determine whether the children are affected by the parent exiting (but the session does).