# What programs acquire a controlling tty?

Tags: unix, process, daemon, tty

The reason for doing a double-fork when daemonizing is to prevent the daemon acquiring a controlling tty ([What is the reason for performing a double fork when creating a daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881388/what-is-the-reason-for-performing-a-double-fork-when-creating-a-daemon/881434#881434))

What are some examples of programs that acquire a controlling tty, and why do they need to do so?

My question is motivated by this problem: [How to monitor child process output and exit status without adversely affecting child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266903/how-to-monitor-child-process-output-and-exit-status-without-adversely-affecting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examples of programs that *intentionally* acquires a controlling tty are `getty` (the program that handles setting up "real" tty lines like consoles, RS-232 serial lines, and modems for use as login terminals) and `sshd` (forks and acquires a pesudo-terminal).

In the context of the reason for double-forking, however, it's much more important to emphasize programs that accidentally (unintentionally) acquire a controlling tty, because that is mainly what the double fork is guarding against, according to the answer you referenced. So an example of a program that *unintentionally* acquires a controlling tty is anything that:

- doesn't already have a controlling tty (typically, a daemon);
- doesn't double fork but calls `setsid()` and is therefore a session leader;
- happens to open a tty without `O_NOCTTY`

In other words: since programs don't generally use `O_NOCTTY` on every open and don't generally intend to acquire controlling terminals when they open things, it's very useful to use the double-fork method to prevent the acquisition from happening.